# How to change a value from a buffer - assignment of read-only location

Tags: c, gtk

How I can modify value from GtkEntryBuffer? At first, I try get text from entry buffer like this:

```
const char *entry_text = gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(data);
```

after, I try modify value to lowercase if value uppercase :)

```
if (entry_text[0] == 65) // if value 'A'
 // try modify to value 'a'
 gtk_entry_buffer_set_text(GTK_ENTRY_BUFFER(data), entry_text[0] += 32, -1);
```

but have error: `assignment of read-only location ‘*entry_text’` What am I doing wrong?

Full example:

```
void lower_button_clicked(GtkWidget *lowerbutton, gpointer data)
{
  const char *entry_text = gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(data);

  for (int i = 0; entry_text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (entry_text[i] >= 65 && entry_text[i] <= 90)
      gtk_entry_buffer_set_text(GTK_ENTRY_BUFFER(data), entry_text[i] += 32, -1);
  }
}
```

i know const cant't change value, but how can I change the value from the buffer and set newer with uppercase text?

Comment: You can not modify `const char *`. Create a mutable copy (use [strdup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup)), modify the copy and then use it, do not forget to delete the copy.

Comment: @TarekDakhran, thank you! I gotta try it